# A question about $ \ln (kc-1)! \sim \ln(c!(c-1)! \dots(c-k)!) + c \cdot\alpha$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, factorial

### Question

I was recently fiddling with some math that me wonder if there was nice asymptotic equation of the form $k<c$:

$$ \ln (kc-1)! \sim \ln(c!(c-1)! \dots(c-k)!) + c \cdot\alpha$$

where $c$ is a variable and $\alpha$ is a constant for large $c$. Can you prove the equation and determine the constants?

### My Fiddling

Consider:

$$ \frac{(2c-1)!}{c!} = (c+1)(c+2)\dots(c+c-1)$$

Now also think of:

$$ (c-1)!  = (c-1)(c-2)\dots (c-(c-1)) $$

Dividing both our equations:

$$ \frac{(2c-1)!}{c!(c-1)!} = \frac{(c+1)(c+2)\dots(c+c-1)}{(c-1)(c-2)\dots (c-(c-1))}$$

Taking $\ln$ both sides and multiplying $1/c$ both sides:

$$ \frac{1}{c}\ln \frac{(2c-1)!}{c!(c-1)!} = \frac{1}{c}\sum_{r=1}^{c-1} \ln \frac{1+\frac{r}{c}}{1-\frac{r}{c}} $$

Taking limit $c \to \infty$ and recognising the R.H.S as an integral:

$$ \lim_{c \to \infty}\frac{1}{c}\ln \frac{(2c-1)!}{c!(c-1)!} = \int_{0^+}^{1^-} \ln \Big( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \Big) dx$$

$$\int_{0^+}^{1^-} \ln \Big( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \Big) dx = (1-x)\ln(1-x) + (1+x)\ln(1+x) \Big|_{0^+}^{1^-} = 2 \ln 2$$

Hence:

$$ \ln(2c-1)! \sim \ln(c!(c-1)!)+ 2c \ln2 $$

Comment: Is $k$ fixed? Then Stirling's formula should be useful.

Comment: Yes, it is ... forgot about that approximation :P